# How to shift elements of a Cvmat in JavaCV

Tags: opencv, shift, javacv

in time I'm writing a little `seam-carving`-application

My problem is to remove the detected "seam" from the image in a efficient way.

I have the following code:

```java
    private void removePathFromImageV(CvMat img, int[] path){

    int band = 3;

    double ch = 0.0;
        for (int y = 0; y < img.rows()-1; ++y){
            for (int x = path[y]-1; x < img.cols()-1; ++x){

                for (int b = 0; b < band; ++b){
                ch = img.get(y,x+1,b);
                img.put(y,x,b,ch);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

is there a option to shift elements from path[y]-1 to img.cols()-1?

greetings

Comment: dont think so. Are you concerned about the efficiency of your actual implementation ?

Comment: yeah, i need a speed up...in time this solution is to slow and it takes a lot of time to solve this function for large images

Comment: Java is very slow for this kind of operation. I would use JNI to speed it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you must suppress pixels at different location for each row, and having an image structure to do that is not efficient, since you have to shift all the pixels after your deleted pixel. You can try to convert your whole image to a data structure that would be efficient for delete operations, e.g. in C++, `std::deque`, a double-ended queue with random access iterators. Then you can easily suppress elements in each row. At the end, you can copy back from your structure to a proper image.

Here is the idea, in C++

```
// assuming image is a CV_8UC3 image
std::deque<std::deque<cv::Vec3b> > pixelsDeq(image.rows, std::deque<cv::Vec3b>(image.cols));
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
    pixelsDeq[i][j] = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j);

// then remove pixels from the path (remove sequentially for all the paths you probably have)
  for (int j = 0; j < image.rows; ++j) {
    pixelsDeq[j].erase(pixelsDeq[j].begin() + paths[j]);


// at the end, copy back to a proper image
cv::Mat output = cv::Mat::zeros(pixelsDeq.size(), pixelsDeq[0].size(), CV_8UC3);
for (int i = 0; i < output.rows; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < output.cols; ++j) {
    output.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = pixelsDeq[i][j];
  } 
}
```

Comment: thanks for snippet, it's a nce mental exercise. I will see to realize something like this in java or jni.

Comment: check out templated containers implementing Collection interface in Java, you can do just the same, but I dont know well Java